# Relation between rest camel and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, rest, apache-camel

I novice in camel.

What i have:
    - rest app deployed on tomcat
    - mongodb

What i want to do:

I want to send request from rest app to camel and camel send request to mongodb and then camel send response to the rest app. (request rest -> camel -> mongodb  , response mongodb->camel->rest )

I can't find information about it.

how i can do this?

my Rest class

```
    @Path("/leave")
public class Leave {

    @GET
    @Path("/all")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getLeaveRequestList(){
        return "{\"status\":200}";   
    }}
```

my route

```
public class CamelRouteConfig extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration().host("localhost").port(8080);
        rest("/leave")
                .post("/all")
                .consumes("application/json")
                .to("stream:out");
    }
}
```

it do nothing. why? - i have no idea

contex method

```
CamelRouteConfig routeConfig = new CamelRouteConfig();
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        try {
            context.addRoutes(routeConfig);
            context.start();
        }finally {
            context.stop();
        }
```

thx for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

You are running Camel as standalone. When you call `context.start()`, the method **does not block**. It means that after starting, `context.stop()` is called immediately. Camel shuts down and REST service goes down with it.

See the following articles: [Running Camel standalone and have it keep runninge](http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html) and [running Camel standalone](http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone.html).

Use class `org.apache.camel.main.Main` and use `run()` method:

> From [run javadoc](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/main/MainSupport.html#run()):
>   Runs this process with the given arguments, and will wait until completed, or the JVM terminates.
>   Throws:
>     Exception